# Indoor olive tree leaves dropping but also showing new growth. Help please

Tags: leaves, olive, wilting

I have had my olive tree for over a year now. It is kept in a pot indoors in a light extension room, and is watered whenever the soil feels dry, every other watering including a diluted solution of olive specific nutrients.

Over the last few months all the leaves in the centre of the tree have been dropping off. I thought it was dying, but now new growth is showing on the outer branches.

I pruned off some of the branches where the leaves were wilting on the entire branch, but more seem to keep wilting.

Any advice would be great, thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: Stop watering so much, and do not use so much fertilizers: they lives fine in dry soil (and not much fertile soils). Especially indoor where you do not want an excessive grow. Many leaves seems very healthy (too much?) Could you add a photo of the fallen leaves (e.g. the bottom part, to exclude some fungi).